# Is it possible to make multi-level directory?

Tags: directory, c

Using `mkdir()` (the C function) I can create a 1-level directory, if I want to create multi_level directory like:

```
folder/subfolder/subsubfolder
```

is it possible? if so, how?

Comment: @l0b0 the OP wanted the `mkdir()` so this is not a duplicate. the `/commandline` BTW does not come from the OP.

Comment: If you were looking for the C code to do this,  a)  you should have mentioned it before everyone answered, and b) asked it on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, not understanding your comment to me? I added the /c tag based on others comments above and also the OP left a comment that he wanted mkdir() on [@schaiba's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74798/7453). The rest of the edits were others, I was the last to add the tag! Please read the edit history before jumping to conclusions!!!

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I propose you look at the history for the edits, Gilles was the one adding the `/command-line` tag. @slm is 'just' the last one to add a revision to the this question (as of now)

Comment: @slm I stand embarrassingly corrected. I blame it on the lack of mobile-friendly layout for the tag edit page 0:-)

Comment: NP, everyone makes mistakes, just pay it forward by keeping things positive next time. Everyone here is human and makes mistakes 8-).

Comment: On SO and also for C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666680/mkdir-p-equivalent-in-c

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
mkdir --parents folder/subfolder/subsubfolder
mkdir -p folder/subfolder/subsubfolder
```

Comment: I want to user mkdir() function in `C`, how to make mkdir() have `-p` ?

Comment: @misteryes Look at the mkdir.c source code in GNU coreutils?

Comment: wow, how to find it?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/ ?

Comment: (`mkdir -p` is standard. `--parents` is GNU, Not Unix.)

Comment: Why was this marked as an answer if the question is about C code?

Comment: @l0b0 That has surprised me, too. And 18 upvotes for this trivial answer whereas my brilliant answers elsewhere get ignored... And now it's even closed as a duplicate though it's absolutely obvious that both questions are seriously different. This is certainly no question for SE to be proud of. :-)

Answer (score 8):

```
mkdir -p /dir1/dir2/dir3
```

Please check the manpage for details:

```
man mkdir
```

Comment: I want to user mkdir() function in C, how to make mkdir() have -p ?

Comment: @misteryes You have to write an algorithm in terms of processing the path as a string, and making multiple system calls.

Answer (score 5):

Something along the lines of:

```
#include <libgen.h>

// safe
void mkdir_recursive(const char *path)
{
    char *subpath, *fullpath;
    
    fullpath = strdup(path);
    subpath = dirname(fullpath);
    if (strlen(subpath) > 1)
        mkdir_recursive(subpath);
    mkdir(path);
    free(fullpath);
}
```

or:

```
#include <string.h>

// only pass a path starting with a trailing slash
// (if path starts with a dot, it will loop and crash)
void mkdir_recursive(const char *path)
{
    char *subpath, *fullpath;
    
    fullpath = strdup(path);
    subpath = basename(fullpath);
    if (strlen(subpath) > 0)
        mkdir_recursive(subpath);
    mkdir(path);
    free(fullpath);
}
```

The first way should always works. The second way should only work if your path starts with a trailing slash, because it will loop on paths starting with a dot.

Answer (score 0):

In case `-p` is not available, argument lists are typically parsed in the order they appear on the command line, thus:

```
mkdir adam adam/bertil adam/bertil/caesar
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
mkdir -p adam/bertil/caesar
```